# How to secure Account data in a WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking to secure my Web API and I have read a lot about it, but I'm stuck at one point.

I'm using a self build bearer-token generator to use tokens to Authenticate my customers and this works.

But where do I put checks if the user is allowed to modify or view the data. 
Example:
I'm a customer of a web shop and I want to view all of my orders(url:"/api/overview").
I click on an order and see that url changes to "api/orders/1". Now the hacker that I am I will just change the "1" to "2" and I will see somebody else order.

Where do I put the security on this, is it in one of the filter layers(Authorization filter?) or is it in the controller?

Or am I missing the hole picture?

Thx, Phoenix

Comment: Do you imply that **1** and **2** are separate customers? Your web application should handle things like that. If you expose your WebAPI you should restrict access to informations to an identifier, like a token or something. By that you can ensure that you can only access the customers informations when successfully authenticated and having permission to view them. There are multiple approaches to achieve that

Comment: @Thyrador Yes, I imply that 1 and 2 are different customers. I know that I have to check it in my Web API the thing is that I don't know in which layer of the web API, in the security layer or in the controller.. If you have some examples on the multiple approaches that will also be a grate help

Comment: Well, we have to discuss the way you have to go beforehand. Since you are about to use Web Api as a REST service your approach is "wrong" when your resource depends authentication. I've ran into the same issue in the past and created a REST service that uses its own session-like mechanism to share essential data between the client (can be MVC, mobile app, third party applications).

But in my case Web Api is the core element and all the clients are just a GUI.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that you will have full control about any data that have to be stored for later use and nearly anything will be kept on the server. The client only requests a resource and the Web Api will pass it (or not, wether if you have access or not).

The only thing that will be send/shared between the client and the Web Api is an authentication token, nothing else.

Just let me know if that is something you consider or if you need a completely different approach.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to metion why this approach is "wrong": REST means stateless, so you request a resource and you get it, no matter what. Session-behaviour and authentication make it stateful, so it's against the definition of REST.
Don't get confused about me saying it's "wrong". A partial stateful approach will do fine, like i described before.
It's just the point to consider if you need to rethink your approach

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. But my REST API is stateless no? I only use tokens to identify my "user". I only want to know where do I check if the user can view the requested data. Because if he is authenticated he may only see his/her data and nothing else.. Do I do this check in the controller or in the filter layer?

Comment: Do you mean your Web Api or MVC controller? I'd check that inside the actual Web Api controller (now it is stateful). There you can decide to use the data, discard it, throw an error or even send a fallback object back to the client.